# Submitting a form to a new window using JavaScript - with Strict DocType

Tags: javascript, forms, target

Ok, so here's my code for submitting the form:

```
document.forms['formid'].submit();
```

The Form Target attribute is deprecated for the DocType I'm using -

http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd

and I really don't want to use a different DocType as a work around for something so simple - so what are my options for submitting to a new window?

Comment: Come join us in the free and easy world of HTML5!

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about doing this from JavaScript (and the title of the question definitely makes it seem like you are), then you should be able to set the "target" attribute from your code.  The W3C police won't arrest you, because your page will still validate.  Once it's parsed into a DOM representation, the doctype is not very relevant (except in so far as it affects quirks mode etc).

```
document.forms['formid'].target = 'http://whatever.com';
document.forms['formid'].submit();
```

Comment: That's kind of what I had in mind - although wasn't sure re W3C police because it just seems to be a different way of doing the very thing which is no longer approved of.

Would it be:
document.forms['formid'].action = 'http://whatever.com';
document.forms['formid'].target = '_blank';
document.forms['formid'].submit();

Though?

Comment: @James Miller well it sort-of *is* doing that, I guess.  That particular "feature" of strict XHTML is what made me quit worrying about XHTML in general. :-) And yes, I believe that will work fine in all relevant browsers, even ancient IE versions.